# Faster convergence of the central limit theorem in special cases

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

The Central Limit Theorem's rate of convergence is $O\left(1/\sqrt{n}\right)$. There are simple distributions for which this rate convergence cannot be improved, for example if the distributions are [i.i.d. Bernoulli trials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157672/convergence-rate-of-the-central-limit-theorem-near-the-center-of-the-distributio). There are some special cases, however, where the convergence rate can be improved, for example if the distributions are [i.i.d. uniform distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (in which case the rate is $O(1/n)$), and an extreme case is if all distributions are normal (in which case the CLT is exact).

My question is: is there a simple "test" one could apply to a probability distribution to estimate the rate of convergence of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}$ to a normal distributions, when $\left(X_i\right)_i$ is a family of i.i.d. random variables from this distribution? Given the examples above, it should probably be about close the $X_i$ are to Gaussian distribution, or maybe how much of them is centered in the tails vs. the center?

Comment: I suggest you to post this question at http://stats.stackexchange.com where more specialized people will advice you